# Recieve element and moving pointers in 2D array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm a beginner in Java, and I need to write a `next()` method, which will return current value from 2D array and move pointer to the next element. It's similar to Iterators's `next()` method.

For example, we may have:

```
int[][] values = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
```

When we are using `next()` at the first time, it returns `1` (pointer moved to next index, now pointer stands at `2`), second use - `2`(+move of pointer), third - `3`(+move pointer), etc.

I wrote some bad code to illustrate what I want to do:

```
public class ArrayConverter {
    private final int[][] values;
    private int upper = 0;
    private int lower = -1;

    public ArrayConverter(int[][] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public int next() {
        lower++;
        int result = 0;
        try {
            result = values[upper][lower];
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a) {
            lower = 0;
            upper++;
            try {
                result = values[upper][lower];
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException r) {
                upper = 0;
                lower = -1;
                System.out.print("Reached the end of data. Indexes will be zeroed.");
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Are there any ways to do it better, especially without using `try/catch` blocks?

Comment: You should never catch an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, just check whether the index is within bounds beforehand.

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.org is a better place to submit code fragments for improvement / suggestions

Comment: @tucuxi I'm pretty sure you mean `codereview.stackexchange.`**`com`** ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use array.length for range checks

Try this:

```
private int upper = 0;
private int lower = 0;

public int next() {
    if(lower >= values[upper].length){
        upper++;
        lower = 0;
    }
    if(upper >= values.length){
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Reached end");
    }
    int result = values[upper][lower++];
    return result;
}
```